# PHP o JS - Actualizar una sección de la página

Tags: javascript, php

Como están? Le estoy dando vuelta a un tema, que no logro encontrarle como hacerlo, tengo una web, donde quiero que solo una seccion de la pagina se actualice, ya que toma datos de la BD, muestra datos nuevos esa seccion. lo unico que logre hacer es:

```
    <section>
    <div id="caja-central">
        <div>
        <?php include('.\Querys\userQuery.php') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

        while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
            <td><?=$row[0]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[1]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[2]?></td>
            <td><?=str_ireplace($serv_regular, $serv_nueva, $row[3])?></td>
            <td class="datos-td"><?=str_ireplace($desc_regular, $desc_nuevo, $row[4])?></td>
            <td><?=$row[5]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
```

Este es mi while, donde toma los datos de una query de SQL server, y los pongo en el DIV - en la bd se agregan datos continuamente, por eso quiero que se recargue o refresque siempre ese div, sin tener que actualizar toda la pagina. JS no tengo nada. Estaba mirando un codigo Ajax, pero estoy tratando de entenderlo.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con **Ajax** para refrescar el **section** de tu pagina al detectar algun _event_. Mandas algún formulario, acción de un botón?, como lo haces?. Edita tu pregunta añadiendo mas detalle y codigo para que sea mas fácil entender tu pregunta, veo que eres nuevo, date una vuelta por [tour] y en [ask], de paso ganas tus primeras medallas.

Comment: Dale gracias por las sugerencias, si soy nuevo en la programacion y estoy intentando realizar este tema, para que me quede mejor que con el reload del META, por eso mis consultas, para poder guiarme y saber que buscar para hacerlo.

Comment: Un reload o Window.location etc. metodos que siempre cargaran por completo el DOM, ya que seria un refresh o redirección, como te mencionaba necesitamos ver tu código HTML, JS, PHP y en base a eso ayudarte.

Comment: ahi edite mi pregunta, y agregue la parte de PHP .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cierro el tema, ya encontre la solución a lo que buscaba, con Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var pageRefresh = 5000; //5 s
setInterval(function() {
refresh();
}, pageRefresh);
});

function refresh() {
$('#contenido').load(location.href + " #contenido");
$('#Contador').load(location.href + " #Contador");
}
```

Gracias.-

Comment: Aquí no se cierran temas. En su lugar, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Además, pulsa en [edit] para explicar cómo funciona tu código. Lee [answer].

Comment: vale, gracias por la info, soy nuevo aca